# How to remove hardcoded path for --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc in CMake using vcpkg toolchain

Tags: cmake, grpc, vcpkg, protoc

I have a working example of building a grpc library in C++ using CMake.
However I need to hardcode the absolute path to the flag
`--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="/home/myusername/dev/lab/MiniGL/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/tools/grpc/grpc_cpp_plugin"`

What I really would like to do is to find something like the environment variable `${PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE}` below for the grpc_cpp_plugin that is required but I just can't find it. i.e.  `${GPRC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}`

Does anyone know if I have missed something simple here?

This is my entire listing of the CMakeLists.txt

```
project(hello_contract_library)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

find_package(protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
#target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE protobuf::libprotoc protobuf::libprotobuf protobuf::libprotobuf-lite)

set(GENERATED_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generated")
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${GENERATED_DIR}")

set(hello_src "${GENERATED_DIR}/hello.pb.cc")
set(hello_hdr "${GENERATED_DIR}/hello.pb.h")
set(hello_grpc_src  "${GENERATED_DIR}/hello.grpc.pb.cc")
set(hello_grpc_hdr  "${GENERATED_DIR}/hello.grpc.pb.h")

# Added to include generated header files
include_directories("${GENERATED_DIR}")

add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT "${hello_src}" "${hello_hdr}" "${hello_grpc_src}" "${hello_grpc_hdr}"
      COMMAND ${PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE}
      ARGS --grpc_out "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generated"
        --cpp_out "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/generated"
        -I "/home/myusername/dev/lab/MiniGL/src/backend/public/contracts"
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="/home/myusername/dev/lab/MiniGL/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/tools/grpc/grpc_cpp_plugin"
        "hello.proto"
      DEPENDS "hello.proto")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${hello_src}
  ${hello_hdr}
  ${hello_grpc_src}
  ${hello_grpc_hdr})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get this for now is by creating your own `.cmake` file which looks for these executables and define this variables. Fortunately Google has an example [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/cmake/common.cmake). You can copy the `common.cmake` to a `cmake` directory that you will include to the project.

This will give you `${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}` for your `--plugin` and `${_GRPC_GRPCPP}` to put in your `target_link_libraries`.

### Example

#### In root directory

```
# common project setup

include(cmake/common.cmake) # comes from Google examples
add_subdirectory(proto)
```

#### In proto directory

```
# Proto files
set(my_protos
    test.proto
)

# Generated sources
set(my_protos_srcs
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/proto/test.pb.cc
)
set(my_protos_hdrs
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/proto/test.pb.h
)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${my_protos_srcs} ${my_protos_hdrs}
    COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
    ARGS --cpp_out ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/proto
        --grpc_out ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/proto
        -I ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/proto
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
        ${my_protos} 
    DEPENDS ${my_protos}
)

add_library(protos
    ${my_protos_srcs}
    ${my_protos_hdrs}
)
target_link_libraries(protos
    ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF}
    ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}
)
```